# Spotfire Script for details-on-demand

Tags: spotfire

**IronPython Script to handle 2 details-on-demand plots which are made from any of the 4 data tables:** 
I have a scatter plot for which I have written a script.. The script allows the end user to display the scatter plot from any of the 8 options..
This scatter plot comes from one datatable always... It has two more details on demand plots i.e. line chart and bar chart.
The data table for these line chart and bar chart depends on what the user has selected from the scatter plot drop-down script..

I am confused how to add data-table part in the script because currently, my script has this structure:

If user select A from drop down list,:
the scatter plot x-axis should be this
the scatter plot y-axis should be that

else if
If user selects B from drop down list:
..
..

I am not sure how can I put data table part from the details on demand plot because if user selected A, then line-chart/bar-chart comes from data table A, and if user selects B, then linechart barchart comes from B data table..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including your code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing this script, though you'll need to duplicate lines 7-9 for each of your visualizations; make a script parameter (in this case Named "tablePlot") to identify the Visualization in question.  The value returned from your DropDownList should be the exact name of your data table; if it isn't, you're going to have to do additional logic (ie, case/if statement) to switch the variable "tblName" to the correct value.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *

myDocument=Application.Document

tblName = Document.Properties["DropDownListPropertyName"]

dt=tablePlot.As[VisualContent]()
newtbl = Document.Data.Tables.Item[tblName]
dt.Data.DataTableReference=newtbl
```

You said you've already got the axes sorted out, but as a more general note for other users, if your columns are the same in each data table, or if you're using a separate property to identify the Category Axis etc, this will be the end of it.  If not, you're going to get an alert telling you the old column name doesn't exist, so you'll have to set those, too.